# Where was "The Light" in Impulse's Dystopian Future?

Tags: dc, young-justice

In *Young Justice: Invasion* (season two of the *Young Justice* television series), the superhero Impulse arrives from the future.  It is revealed through his memories that the Reach has subjected humanity and, seemingly, the metahuman population.  In order to prevent this future, Impulse travels back to the present in order to help the Justice League and Young Justice.

Based on what has been revealed from Impulse's memories and what was currently occurring during the television season, it is (more or less) easy to infer what happened to any organization in opposition to the Reach:

> the Flash would have died, Blue Beetle and Green Beetle would still be under control of the Reach, six members of the Justice League would have been sentenced on Rimbor, and the remaining members of the Justice League and Young Justice would have been killed, subjected, or exiled.

**But what happened to the Reach's partner: "The Light"?**
Since they were partners with the Reach, it seems that they would have been shown privileges (or, at the very least, leniency) that other humans and metahumans would not have had.
Plus, "The Light" appears to always be several steps ahead of the Justice League and the Reach and always plans for "contingencies."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two episodes that require attention here.

First, obviously, is Bloodlines. The future isn't just dystopian, it's destroyed. It appears that a war has been fought and Bart dressed like a refugee before he came to the past.

The other episode is Summit which gives a lot of insight into the Light/Reach "alliance." During the conference, The Reach Ambassador openly states that he (and The Reach) consider the Earth and its population, including The Light, to be the property of The Reach. Then, Aqualad reveals that The Light has been subverting The Reach all along so they (The Light) could rule the galaxy.

This next part is pure speculation:

We can easily assume that the first targets of The Reach were The Justice League, The Team and any other heroes or military power on Earth willing/able to stand up to them. Following that, and based on what was revealed in Summit, it's likely that The Light would have made its move using the Meta-humans it was keeping out of The Reach's...reach (I hate that sentence). That would have started the second part of the war for control of Earth and, according to Bart's memories, The Light lost.